# How to upload an image on mysql database in PHP

Tags: php, image

I need a help to upload and show an image from a database in PHP, I created a database that name is students contains the ID, image size,and image name, is there is a way to do that?
I searched on youtube about this but I found this code, but this code save to a directory.

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES["myfile"] ["name"];
$type = $_FILES["myfile"] ["type"];
$size = $_FILES["myfile"] ["size"];
$temp = $_FILES["myfile"] ["tmp_name"];
$name = $size.$size .$name ;
$error = $_FILES["myfile"] ["error"];
if ($error > 0){
die ("Error uploading image");
}else{

move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
echo "Upload Completed";

}

?>
```

So, is there any way to save an image to a database and view it from a database?

Comment: You're most likely wanting to upload the image to your server, then store it's location in your database

Comment: What FDL said,  it is technically possible to store image data inside a database, in 99% of cases the sensible thing to do is store the image's filename and path in the database, and store the image itself in the file system.

Comment: I did that exactly before but I faced a problem, when I upload an image it location is saved into a new row but what I need is to save the image location to an exist row.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it into a MySQL table as a Blob but this isn't a really a good idea. Explanation here: http://www.hockinson.com/programmer-web-designer-denver-co-usa.php?s=47

Do what FDl said in the comments. Give each image a unique name and save it to your server, then save its unique name into your database.

Comment: I did what FDL said exactly before but I faced a problem, when I upload an image it location is saved into a new row but what I need is to save the image location to an exist row